# How to check if a term is parent to another?

Tags: terms

I have made a product page. Wich lists all products site.com/products. At the product page there is a navigation wich lists all the terms in the taxonomy 'kategori'. The taxonomy is set to hierarchical, so i can make parent terms. I list all the terms with:

```
  <div class="produkt_nav"><h3><a href="/produkter/">Produkter</a></h3>
  <?php $cam_brands = get_terms('kategori', 'hide_empty=1'); ?>
  <ul>
    <?php foreach( $cam_brands as $brand ) : ?>
      <li>
        <a href="<?php echo get_term_link( $brand->slug, 'kategori' ); ?>">
          <?php echo $brand->name; ?>
        </a>

    <?php endforeach ?>
  </ul>

  </div>
```

It gives me:

- Main category
- Main 2 category
- Parent to main 3
- Main 3 category
- Main 4 category

I need to change the code so i get it to show:

```
- Main category
- Main 2 category
- Main 3 category   
  X Parent to main 3
- Main 4 category
```

How can put a different class to parent terms and list the terms as a tree?

Comment: Check for `$brand->parent_ID`, if set apply new class. Other than that, I'd suggest you use a custom Walker http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/Walker_Class instead of a loop.

Comment: Also look at [`wp_list_categories`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [wp_list_categories()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories) where the `hierarchical` argument is set to true by default , something like this:

```
<div class="produkt_nav"><h3><a href="/produkter/">Produkter</a></h3>
    <ul>
    <?php wp_list_categories('taxonomy' => 'kategori'); ?> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!, I used <?php wp_list_categories($args);?> and defind an $args array :)